# What do we do with answers that are entirely copied and improperly attributed (only a "reference" link or similar is included)?

Tags: discussion, plagiarism, attribution

I stumbled across a long and in depth answer earlier that thoroughly explained a topic. It seemed quite helpful though oddly verbose for SO, and then I noticed at the bottom there was a reference link. The answer was a blogpost, copied entirely with seemingly no changes whatsoever (besides formatting).

The user hadn't even added attribution until it was asked for in the comments. But even with attribution this seems questionable. The user is effectively passing info off as their own by not highlighting that the entire answer comes from their source (it's just listed at the bottom as "reference" with no explanation). It's also not the *best* fit to answer this way since they're addressing the topic but it's not written specifically in response to the OP's question.

It's also not clear if the source allows for their content to be reposted elsewhere, and I suspect that the user in question is not concerned about that since they didn't even initially have basic attribution. But what is the protocol here? Can I step in as a user to edit posts to make the sourcing clearer and educate the user on the need for permission and attribution? Is it better to let a moderator handle it as it's bordering on plagiarism?

Comment: Yeah, no, adding a "Reference" link at the bottom doesn't count as proper attribution, for the very reason you state: the user is implicitly passing off the content as their own by not explicitly indicating that it's *not* their own. The guidelines are given here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing and users are expected to follow **all** of them, no matter what they tell you.

Comment: Nice related articles there ----> , since this is asked quite frequently ;)

Comment: @Gimby Do you have a good dupe about off site plagiarism? I mostly find results about copying SO posts or posts entirely lacking any attribution (links and all).

Comment: @BoltClock Thank you! I was misinformed before but now I've flagged appropriately.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan I'm not exactly sure how far you want to go with this question. Does it go as far as worrying about legal ramifications? In any case this existing related article contains a nice step-by-step coverage: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289393/was-i-being-a-bully-a-busybody-or-helpful

Comment: @Gimby: Copying off-site content by itself is pretty distinct from copying on-site content. The latter can be resolved mostly by marking duplicates. The former has to be handled differently, since you can't mark a question as a dupe of an off-site source.

Comment: @boltclock the steps taken there still pretty much cover what you can and should do for plagiarized off-site content if you ask me. Especially step 1: communicate before acting, give the copy artist the benefit of the doubt to see it your way and do the right thing. Which in the case of content plagiarized off-site will be only one course of action - delete, if that is still possible. So I ask you in all honesty: where in that process am I missing the point?

Comment: Note that it's ok to take from your own blog (although you should mention it's *yours*).

Comment: Did it by any chance start by being a link-only answer? Maybe the answerer took the LQP comments eriously, and "added code":P

Comment: @AndrasDeak That probably can happen, but this was literally the opposite. :P

Comment: Related (not a duplicate): *[Consensus on self-promotion and spam](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348489/consensus-on-self-promotion-and-spam)*. See also [the linked questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/348489?sort=newest).

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Before I start, there is a [help article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) dedicated to the overarching issue of referencing content from external sources. The guidelines therein apply to pretty much any situation involving referencing external content.

Now, there are two major issues at play here.

### Attribution

The first major issue is in providing attribution for copied content, arguably the more important of the two. Here's what the help article says:

> If you copy (or closely rephrase/reword) content that you did not create into something you post on Stack Overflow (e.g., from another site or elsewhere on Stack Overflow), make sure you do all of the following:
>
> - Provide a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#links) to the original page or answer
> - [Quote](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#simple-blockquotes) only the relevant portion
> - Provide the name of the original author

(with an example to boot)

The link to the original source serves both as acknowledgement of the source, and as a way for readers to verify the source (for as long it remains available anyway). The blockquote markup is used to indicate, typographically, the portions of the content that come from that source, and therefore **not original content**. If the name of the original author is unavailable (as is the case with this very help article, funnily enough), simply naming the source itself will do.

So, **simply tacking a "Reference" link at the bottom of a wall of unquoted text**, as is the habit of an alarming number of users, **does *not* count as proper attribution**, for the very reason you state: the user is still implicitly passing off the content as original, by not expressly indicating that it's from elsewhere. The association of the content to the user is otherwise expressed by their user card at the bottom of the post — incidentally, much more conspicuously than the "Reference" link.

**Answers that fail to follow *all* of the steps above are considered plagiarism and subject to deletion by a moderator.** As an editor, if you believe the user could benefit from an example, you may help by adding blockquotes and editing the link text to explicitly name the source, for example. But don't feel like you are obligated to do so; the responsibility of providing this attribution falls first and foremost on the user posting the answer. You should flag any cases of plagiarism you see regardless, but *especially* flag if you notice a *pattern* of this coming from specific users. [We have a mod message that's designed specifically for these users.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269315/changes-to-discourage-plagiarism/269319#269319)

### Copying partial content vs entire content

The second major issue is in the amount of content that's copied. Although this doesn't influence whether something is considered plagiarism, it's nevertheless important to keep in mind. Here's what the help article says:

> Do *not* copy the complete text of external sources; instead, use their words and ideas to support your own. And *always* give proper credit to the author and site where you found the text, **including a direct link to it**.

The first half of this paragraph is pretty clear: **we expect answers on Stack Overflow to be original contributions by and large**; copying entire texts wholesale is incredibly frowned upon (and can often be seen as lazy on part of the poster). For an example of how to "use [someone else's] words and ideas to support your own", look no further than *this very paragraph*. See what I'm doing? I'm quoting a paragraph from a reliable source to show you that I'm not just talking through my hat.

Granted, there are some situations where indeed there isn't much more to be said than one or two well-written paragraphs from a documentation section or a language specification. That's fine, you're not going to get into trouble for doing that every now and then. Just remember that you still need to provide attribution and quote the text as required above.

But if you find that you're consistently posting answers that consist of little more than text from other sources, or if you find yourself about to highlight and copy practically an entire document just to answer one specific question, that's when you need to take a step back and ask yourself if it really is necessary to copy all 27 of those paragraphs. Can you distill the text to just the portions that are immediately relevant to the question at hand? Can you then elaborate on this text, forming an answer that's tailored to that specific question that you can be proud to call your own?

If so, then you have yourself a winning formula for contributing well-researched *and* well-constructed answers to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Compare this answer with [this other answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251389/when-is-using-an-other-posters-content-plagiarism/251583#251583).

Comment: ... I just realized the second section sounds more like it would belong in a canonical answer rather than the specific question. Ah well. Canonicals. We need more of those. (Not the company.)

Comment: Would [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41500356/4342498) qualify as an exception or should i be flagged/deleted?

Comment: @NathanOliver: Given that they're in the habit of doing this sort of thing I'd say it should be flagged (but of course now that we're here...) and deleted (which I have done).

Comment: "*the user is still implicitly passing off the content as original, by not expressly indicating that it's from elsewhere.*" I disagree that including a reference attribution is still attempting to pass off the content as original. That claim is antithetical to the act of including a reference link.

Comment: "Compare this answer with this other answer." I was hoping that I'd see several word-for-word identical paragraphs ;)