# Why was my answer with 12 upvotes deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, specific-answer

I [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67083096/6451573) [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67083039/15160601) and my answer had 12 upvotes on it but now I can't find it. Can someone tell me why?

Also, everything on my profile was edited like I never answered the question or earned 120 reputation. This is confusing me ...
I hope a moderator will see my post.

Comment: If you mean the deleted answer, a moderator closed it due to plagiarization

Comment: @Yatin no I mean on the reputation graph, usually when you loose reputations, it appears on the graph but now it didn't change and the maximum of earned reputations decreased..

Comment: Like it was totaly removed from the SO databases

Comment: I can see my other posts that moderators deleted so why I can't see this one ?

Comment: You can't see it because it has been deleted and you don't have enough rep to see. And I already told you *why* it was deleted and by what whom. Interestingly, the username that answered the question (before the account was deleted) was different from your current account.

Comment: Please don't delete a question immediately after someone has answered it. We've already informed the moderator who was actually responsible for getting your answer removed, in case you want to hear it from the horse's mouth.

Answer (score 24):

Your answer was a verbatim copy of [a comment from Hacker News](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=26799457), presumably because the question itself is based on [a tweet by Ned Batchelder](https://twitter.com/nedbat/status/1382027078816653319) that was posted mere hours before the question, went viral, and landed on HN. Ironically, the question itself doesn't mention his tweet either so it just comes off as an extremely contrived coincidence — I'm sure Ned himself doesn't care despite being active here, but still.

Anyway, your answer was not only deleted, but also disassociated from your account, which is why it's like you never answered the question. This is different from normal deletion of posts. I'm guessing the reason the answer was disassociated is because 12 upvotes in 2 weeks for an answer that contained *only* unattributed copied content, is a significant amount of reputation from an answer that was breaking the rules on plagiarism. Although deleting it the normal way would've given you a chance to edit the answer to either remove the copied comment or add attribution to it (you did edit it to quote content from elsewhere while still failing to account for the copied comment), restoring the answer after the changes would've returned the reputation from those 12 upvotes to you. And it would still be an answer consisting of no original content (unless... you were the OP of the comment on HN?).

Please don't post answers that consist only of content copied (or plagiarized) from elsewhere. We expect answers on Stack Overflow to contain at least some original content, citing content from other sources as references to *support* their original content rather than [standing alone as answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321299/answers-entirely-copied-though-properly-attributed/321326#321326). Yes, it seems dubious that the question itself made no reference to Ned's tweet considering it was the reason for the question's existence to begin with, but that's a separate and much less clear-cut issue.