# Why did a moderator immediately delete answers with "insufficient attribution" instead of commenting and waiting for edits?

Tags: discussion, answers, deleted-answers, moderators, plagiarism

Earlier yesterday a moderator deleted a bunch of my answers due to no attribution of sources or "insufficient attribution". I understand that I did something wrong, but I don't see why they had to deleted immediately upon sight. On another site a moderator saw this and simply commented on my answer to add my attributions (or edited it themself).

Is it different on SO compared to sites on SE? I honestly think commenting before deleting gives the user more grace time and leeway to understand what they did wrong. Plus, now the users who asked the questions are going to be confused on why the answer they see helpful are gone.

Comment: Stack Overflow is the biggest site on the network and there are thousands of questions and answers being posted every day. The moderators here don't have time to follow up and make sure you add attribution. If you fix your answer you can always undelete or post a new answer that contains proper attribution.

Comment: @BSMP If the post was deleted by a moderator, then reposting it is usually not a good idea. If not fixed, then that's handled as if the user is intentionally ignoring the instructions they've gotten from moderators, which is unlikely to end well, unless the user later changes their behavior. If the post is fixable, then the best thing to do is to edit the existing post and raise an "in need of moderator intervention" flag explicitly stating that you believe the issues are resolved and asking for the post to be evaluated for undeletion.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Stack Overflow is the original site, and the one that keeps truest to the original mission. Its moderators have more experience and tend to handle things closer to the way they were originally intended to be handled. By contrast, other Stack Exchange sites have newer moderators with less experience who tend to reinvent the rules and responses as they go.

Additionally, Stack Overflow operates at a vastly larger scale than any other Stack Exchange site. This means its moderators simply don't have time to stop and hold users' hands, even if they wanted to do so, because that doesn't scale with the amount of users and posts that we get. Stack Overflow's *Meta* site (this one) is larger than almost any other *main* Stack Exchange site. Stack Overflow *itself* (the main site) is multiple orders of magnitude larger than any other Stack Exchange site. So, even if the policies that other Stack Exchange moderators invent are "better" or "nicer", they generally don't scale to Stack Overflow, and you won't see Stack Overflow moderators adopting them. Stack Overflow moderators are extremely experienced, very good at their jobs, and we want to help (after all, we're also volunteers), but, the best way to think about it is, we don't have the time or the patience for putting up with nonsense. We *do* admittedly have a tendency to delete first and ask questions later, something which you might not see on other Stack Exchange sites.

That said, **this is not one of those cases where Stack Overflow moderators were being more harsh than necessary. Answers that don't meet the site's minimum standards should be immediately deleted.** After deletion, you have as much time as you want to edit and improve the answer—deleted answers can always be edited by the original author. Once you've done so, you can flag the answer for moderator attention, asking for it to be reviewed and (potentially) undeleted.

(Note that you cannot undelete an answer that has been deleted by a moderator—the system doesn't allow the author or anyone else to do so. Posts deleted by a moderator *must* be undeleted by a moderator—*any* moderator. But in this case, that's a good thing, as it gives whichever moderator handles your "review for undeletion" flag a chance to actually review your edits and see if you corrected the issues. If not, they would then [hopefully] provide you with more detailed guidance, perhaps a link to a Meta Q&A, a Help Center article, or something like that…assuming you actually made a good-faith effort to improve the post.)

There is no reason to *ever* leave problematic content visible on the site (in an undeleted state). It simply isn't necessary, and it isn't the appropriate way to handle this type of thing on *any* Stack Exchange site. If you've had other SE moderators doing that, then they were deviating from established policy/procedure, possibly out of ignorance or perhaps out of a misguided attempt to be "nice". They did not do you or any other users any favors by doing so.

Even indulging your position that moderators should comment before deleting… how long should we wait after commenting before deleting? How should we remember to come back and check up on it later? How would we scale to do this for thousands of posts on the site? Why should we leave problematic content visible on the site for as long as it takes you to fix it (even if you fix it within 24 hours, which would be a pretty good response time)? That content sets a bad example for other users, and it brings down the overall quality of the site.

Comment: So it's **wrong** for a SE moderator to do that?

Comment: Yes, generally. I mean, consider a janitor who walks by a spill, choosing only to put up a sign saying "possible slip hazard". That *can* be justified if they have something more urgent they need to attend to, and it's certainly what they should do while they are going to get the mop. But if they just leave it for hours or days, then they aren't really doing their job. The root cause of the spill is no more their business than the motivation of the user who posted the answer is the business of moderators: their job is to keep the place clean.

Comment: @DialFrost on a side note - to elaborate on Cody's point about scale - have a look at https://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday

Comment: In addition, when you copy answers from another post in their entirety, it is clear the copier doesn't have an answer of their own. There was no original content in the first place, and that alone is sufficient to delete a post. *This is not something you can remedy with a reference link*. And that's not even considering if a bounty was in play; we can't re-assign to a more deserving answer (one that wasn't a copy-pasta), so the _only option remaining_ is to delete the post to at least remove the bounty.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: Indeed. The canonical may be *[Answers entirely copied though properly attributed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321299/)* - e.g., *"copying entire texts wholesale is incredibly frowned upon"*.

Comment: Re *"There is no reason to ever leave problematic content visible on the site (in an undeleted state)."*: Some uninformed users would say [necroposting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_forum#Necroposting) (probably beaten into them on traditional forums). Perhaps address that as well?

Comment: And for what it's worth, the semi-tree map hides the scale quite a bit, properly scaled, it [looks more like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GG2Fw.png).

Comment: @PeterMortensen What does "necroposting" have to do with anything discussed in this answer? We do not consider that to be "problematic content", unless *what you've necroposted* is problematic.

Comment: [Maybe of interest?](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5781/should-we-take-action-on-posts-from-experienced-users-with-uncited-quotes?cb=1)

Comment: "*Deleting a post only for lack of attribution is overkill. Deletion is for irredeemable garbage like spam, comments in an answer, and one-liner answers when there's already an upvoted full answer.*" - mod (Is this correct?)

Comment: @DialFrost I can't moderate the mods across the Stack Exchange network, although I do try to on occasion (and they don't really like it). But no, that quoted statement is absolutely not correct.

Comment: If a mod deletes a post, the user cannot undelete it. That's by design. However, they *can* flag it, which is how they would notify the mods that they've improved it and want to have it re-evaluated for undeletion. We do this for "not an answer" posts (e.g., answers that contain nothing but an off-site link, with no explanation), we do it for borderline spam (e.g., answers that are an attempt to answer, but failed to include the proper disclaimer of affiliation with the recommended tool/library), and we will do it for posts with improper attribution/citations.

Comment: @CodyGray However, when an answer is deleted by a mod the author is not notified. Imagine if the answer was posted weeks or months ago there's no way of knowing it has been deleted unless the author checks back. Would the author be warned by a sudden drop in reputation? I'm not sure. But if the answer had not earned any upvotes, and was later deleted by a mod. How would they know? How would they improve/fix their post and flag it?

Comment: @DialFrost how did you know a number of answers had been deleted? Did you see a drop in reputation? Were the answers recently posted so when you revisited the pages you saw your answers had disappeared?

Comment: They were my answers @Mari-LouA, I dropped about 1.6k, a mod deleted them and they were sort of recent

Comment: Ooh, that's a fair bit of rep loss @DialFrost. Sorry about that. Consider also the possibility that your contributions were flagged more than once by users who want the rules to be respected. How did you think you could quote/cite partial answers without giving attribution? Have I not taught you anything! ;) See: [Attribution: the good and the bad](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5679/attribution-the-good-and-the-bad)

Comment: Hehe, I sort of forgot about it slowly, but I'm fixing them currently :P@Mari-LouA my bad

Comment: @Mari-LouA There's no reason why a moderator cannot choose to leave a comment in such cases. In fact, in virtually *all* cases where an answer is deleted for plagiarism or insufficient attribution, even a busy Stack Overflow moderator will leave a comment explaining this. A comment on the deleted post would still notify the author.

Comment: Also if that same post was deleted within minutes?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yes, comments made by moderators after a post is deleted do notify all users who would normally be notified (e.g. the post author, any `@` notification, etc.) Notifications for comments made by moderators prior to deletion remain in the user's inbox if the comment was posted less than 30 minutes prior to the post being deleted. There's at least one MSE/MSO post giving more detail on exactly how that works, but I don't have a link handy.