# Restoration of posts

Tags: discussion, support, plagiarism

I am raising the question as I have ran out of option to flag the post for moderator intervention.

Recently, I have found that my popular post have been deleted due to

1. Posting content from Oracle official documentation OR LinkedIn author official documentation.
2. Embedding image with out license

My deleted Post 1:

[Java heap terminology: young, old and permanent generations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129044/java-heap-terminology-young-old-and-permanent-generations/36159270#36159270)

My deleted post 2:

[How should I have explained the difference between an Interface and an Abstract class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18777989/how-should-i-have-explained-the-difference-between-an-interface-and-an-abstract/34978606#34978606)

My deleted post 3:

[Which cluster type should I choose for Spark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28664834/which-cluster-type-should-i-choose-for-spark)

My deleted post 4:

[Interface vs Abstract Class (general OO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761194/interface-vs-abstract-class-general-oo)

My deleted post 5:

[What is the purpose of shuffling and sorting phase in the reducer in Map Reduce Programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22141631/what-is-the-purpose-of-shuffling-and-sorting-phase-in-the-reducer-in-map-reduce/33395854#33395854)

EDIT: Changes after following suggestions

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now look at feasibility of restoring the posts.

Comment: "The moderators who have deleted my posts did not check other posts in the same questions, who have done same things." - then raise flags on those posts. We deal with an obscene amount of posts in a day, so stuff slips through the cracks.

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine *"I have ran out of option to flag the post for moderator intervention."*

Comment: @NickstandswithUkraine To be specific, they're flag banned, and not a single flag was used to flag other problematic content. But the general statement still holds; those posts _should_ be flagged, even if OP currently can't

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine *"not a single flag was used to flag other problematic content"* ... obviously. Because they're flag banned (as everyone who's been paying recent attention to meta [knows](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/423991/deletion-of-plagiarism-posts#comment952565_423991)). Saying to flag when they can't flag is simply unhelpful though.

Comment: I believe what Zoe is therefore saying, @NickstandswithUkraine , is the OP needs to *wait* until they are not flagged banned. Which, from the post they were linked to before, will be at most a week long ban.

Comment: Only moderators have the full picture here, but I sense a strong "boy who cried wolf" sentiment. Even if you have a good reason to flag a post right now, your past flagging history is now working against you.

Comment: On [Which cluster type should I choose for Spark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28664834/which-cluster-type-should-i-choose-for-spark) you *appear* to have posted a [new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75896684) instead. Though you have attempted to edit the [deleted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34657719), posting a new answer (which I *think* is using your own words?) is could result in that answer being deleted too; you should be (as already directed) fixing your existing answer(s) and then using a custom moderator flag.

Comment: The last 3 points on my answers are not in LinkedIn post. Earlier I posted all under one umbrella. I have added my self observations also

Comment: Everything happened in 2 fine days, so quick. I realized that it happened only to me since other posts in same questions are not impacted. It may be one guy, who flagged my post

Comment: @E_net4, exactly. Due to the reason, I posted question here. Since there is change only in my posts, I am little demotivated. But I am not looking for deletion of other's posts. I have edited answers and looking for restore deleted ones

Comment: @ThomA, new answer is based on my learnings in last few years, which does not reflect old post by 100%

Comment: *"Since there is change only in my posts"* I can assure you that it is *not* just your posts that are deleted due to plagiarism, @Ravindrababu .

Comment: Thanks @ThomA. I still think Official documentation sites like Oracle definitions quoting should not be quoted as plagiarism. For example, if you write Newton's third law somewhere in same wordings, "Every action has equal and opposite reaction", it can not be plagiarism as it's definition and once you know it, you can use it

Comment: I see tons of posts with images still, which are top rated.

Comment: Quoting with citation isn't plagiarism, @Ravindrababu . No one has said otherwise. The problem is you *did not* quote and cite; I would personally say you have not taken the time to understand *why* your content was deleted based on  your [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/423995/restoration-of-posts?noredirect=1#comment952621_423995)

Comment: @ThomA : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761194/interface-vs-abstract-class-general-oo?page=2&tab=trending#tab-top   Let me know if it's still plagiarism

Comment: @Ravindrababu did you flag it for undeletion after fixing it? Note: If you have a declined flag before fixing the post it does not count.

Comment: I am unable to see any of these additional answers you claim plagiarized external sources. If these other answers are not quoting and citing an external source, they should be deleted, until such time they properly cite and quote the external material. Specifically the answers you say have images, I can't see them, are you sure you are not just reporting plagiarism on answers that have already been deleted? Just because another answer has plagiarized content does not mean you shouldn't properly cite and quote the material you used.

Comment: @SecurityHound, I have added author name in question now

Comment: *If* you have fixed the post(s), then (as mentioned many times) *flag* the post(s) with a custom moderator flag and explain you have addressed the plagiarism issues and how, @Ravindrababu . We, as users/curators, **cannot** undelete your post(s) as they are moderator deleted.

Comment: The answer you claimed contained a diagram does not contain a diagram, and the domain you said it was from, does not even work. The external information in the answer, is quoted and cited, and thus wouldn't be considered plagiarism. The other example, should be modified, to make it clear that some of the content is from the documentation website.

Comment: The answer you say copied an image, is properly cited, although the image should have been quoted.  I have went ahead and fixed that for the author.

Comment: If what you're *actually* asking for here is the undeletion of your own posts, then the content of other posts doesn't matter (and shouldn't be in the question, or at least not be 90% of your question's content). What matters is the content of your posts combined with the post's history and your actions. The argument "somebody else is violating the rules, so I should be allowed to too" is almost never a legitimate argument. Lack of uniformity of enforcing the rules for content is almost always due to the *huge* amount of content which SO has and the *very limited* curation resources available.

Comment: Given the great difference between the available curation resources and the amount of content which needs curation, there will *always* be disparities in the level of compliance to rules throughout the site. For things, like plagiarism, which typically requires the intervention of an elected moderator, the disparity is *primarily* that one thing has been brought to our attention while something else has not. The primary way which issues are brought to moderator attention is through flags. If there's a plagiarism issue with some posts and/or a user, then raise a flag.

Comment: There's even a shiny new "plagiarism" flag that's just the right flag to raise on plagiarism. Yes, if you're currently banned from raising flags, then you won't be able to raise any flags about the plagiarism of others. Flag bans usually last for about a week (varies based on when your flags were declined and how many flags you're raised). Moderators *can't* directly change the state of a flag ban. The system applies flag bans automatically. So, you'll just need to wait prior to being able to raise more flags.

Comment: @SecurityHound, even for non-existent link quoting, still post is not un-deleted. Please have a look at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28664834/which-cluster-type-should-i-choose-for-spark

Comment: @SecurityHound, since I have one image from official documentation after modifying answer, post was deleted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129044/java-heap-terminology-young-old-and-permanent-generations/36159270#36159270

Comment: @Makyen, I raised this question as I don't have that flag enabled as of now for me for a week. Other part in my questions, not complaining about others but have same consistency. When my post is deleted for some reasons,  other posts in the same question also needs to be checked.

Comment: If that is your *actual* issue, then your question here is unclear. You *explicitly* state in this question that that is *not* what your concern is / what you're asking for.

Comment: That the five answers you've linked in the question have been deleted as plagiarism makes it likely you've been sent a moderator message about plagiarism. If your issue is with the current handling of your posts with respect to plagiarism, then you could also respond to such a moderator message (if you were sent one). I should probably note that users can only respond once to each moderator message, but can respond again if a moderator posts another response. Responses to moderator messages can be long and detailed, so if that's available to you, it might be a reasonable option.

Comment: @Makyen, I just want to confirm the 5 deleted posts in current state still fall under plagiarism OR can be restored. I can't initiate the flag for next one week and hence I posted this query for action

Comment: @Ravindrababu - Just reading the first sentence I could tell [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28664834/which-cluster-type-should-i-choose-for-spark/75896684#75896684) answer was not properly cited and quoted. When I can search entire sentences, and find results, that is plagiarism. *If your sources no longer work, that's fine, that is the reason you quote and cite your sources before you submit the answer* [This](https://www.edureka.co/community/15683/which-cluster-type-should-i-choose-for-spark) as an example, appears to be plagiarized from whatever source you originally quoted

Comment: Most of the websites about ([Spark, YARN, and Mesos](https://christiantejadapacheco.wordpress.com/2017/04/04/apache-spark-cluster-managers-yarn-mesos-or-standalone/)) all appear to be plagiarized. I have found multiple websites which clearly contain plagiarized content.

Comment: @SecurityHound, our SE question and answers are copied there. Just check our 
 content there.

Comment: @Ravindrababu - Who exactly is "our"? Where is it copied? Every answer you point out is deleted except one answer which still has significant plagiarism issues. Most of answers from other authors, you point out do not cite resources, actually do cite resources properly.

Comment: @Ravindrababu - I am not willing to spend time, to point out plagiarism issues with your answers, when your issues are pretty sever. You have more than enough professional experience to determine what is or isn't plagiarism.

Comment: I took this author at their word that a question contained an image that should be quoted; their analysis of that determination was 100% wrong, making me look like a fool when I attempted to address that issue.  Plagiarized is bad, and given that the author does not seem to understand this fact, it proves their deleted content should remain deleted. I will treat any additional interaction with this user as non-serious because of their improper claims that another answer used an image from another source, when that wasn't actually the case

Comment: What I don’t understand is why the author wants such unhelpful answers to be restored. If they don’t plagiarize content in the future they won’t have future answers deleted for plagiarism. Yes; plagiarized content is unhelpful

Comment: It's quite easy to distinguish between your use of Newton's law and copying Oracle documentation: you didn't have to copy the law from an external source, but you had to for the official docs. The latter should absolutely be cited every time. It is clearly not "common knowledge" if you have to copy it word-for-word. The former even should be cited depending on whether the intended audience would consider it common knowledge, but even that's easy (*Here's Newton's 3rd law:*). "Once you know it, you can use it," is false. Even if I memorize *War and Peace* verbatim, it's not suddenly mine.

Comment: Secondly, since you clarified that you are asking only for un-deletion of your posts, can you please remove references to other posts and to moderator action pertaining to them? It really reads like a "whataboutism" to leave it in, but at best, it's just irrelevant.

Comment: Removed other post references

Comment: It's now not clear what the point of your post is. PS Please do not edit a question post in a way that invalidates reasonable posted answers. PS Now please remove the plagiarism in all your other posts.

Comment: Please read the edit help & advanced help & use block quote format for blocks of text that are quoted. Not boldface.

Comment: ok. I am updating the posts. In few posts, I used quote formatting for author question. while answering, which I will correct too.

Comment: You have ~930 SO answer posts. There's no need to comment here as you edit them.

Comment: The saga: *[Deletion of plagiarism posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/423991/)* (8 hours prior. Likely to be automatically deleted) and *[Improper implementation of the plagiarism rule](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424443/)* (26 days later, 2023-04-30. Now deleted).

Comment: @PeterMortensen Missed [one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424405/implementation-of-plagiarism-rules), 2023-04-27, also deleted.

Comment: This behavior is shocking. I personally identified and flagged more than 10 additional answers that were plagiarizing content at different levels of obviousness. Some of the worst offenders were verbatim copies. I think the worst thing is some of the content has been around for years, and the amount that is plagiarized in what I flagged, is absolutely shocking. It’s only about flagging plagiarized content

Comment: @SecurityHound, I can seen stackoverflow content copy in 5+ other sites. The article you quoted  on Bridge pattern in 2019 and myst post was posted i 2016

Comment: @Ravindrababu - That’s only an example I found today, I found, more obvious examples that plagiarized Oracle documentation. You still copied, verbatim, at least one sentence (or more) from a book. Honestly, i am not looking to discuss the cases of plagiarism, only noting the sheer amount that has been found so far is shocking

Comment: @Ravindrababu Forgive me if I misunderstand your latest message, but others committing plagiarism, or copying from Stack Overflow, is not an excuse for you to do the same.

Comment: If a post of yours has been deleted for plagiarism, but in reality, it is the other way around, and some article online plagiarized you, flag your own post for moderator attention, and explain that.

Comment: @Andreasdetestscensorship, I am not saying I will do plagiarism.  I  am just saying I found multiple websites copied my content. Someone should not say that I copied from those posts. Date of article to be checked.

Comment: Yes. I quoted content from oracle documentation for authenticity. In my view, every Java developer should read it for better understanding. Moderator message I got on March end says I linked websites but did not use quote formatting and hence posts are delered

Comment: Irrespective of theory, I have contributed code and that code is my own.

Answer (score 28):

You were sent the following guidance in a moderator message:

> **Posts containing content from other sources must:**
>
> - Include the name of the original author.
> - Include a link to the original source.
> - Make it clear (using [quote formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#simple-blockquotes)) **which parts of the answer are copied, and from where.** *Just putting a link to the original source somewhere in the post is not enough*, because it does not make it clear that it is the source of the content. For more information, see [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/321326).
> - Add your own content to the post. It should not be entirely (or almost entirely) copied content.
>
> The third rule is the one you've most frequently failed to follow.
>
> Also, even if you change some of the wording or code a bit, you still must credit the original source. As a general rule, if it's recognizable when you compare the two side-by-side, it needs to give credit.

Quite simply, **you have not followed this guidance.**

Let's take [the first post you mention](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36159270/208273).  Here's a paragraph from it that you include with no quote formatting or attribution to a source whatsoever.

> The Permanent generation contains metadata required by the JVM to describe the classes and methods used in the application. The permanent generation is populated by the JVM at runtime based on classes in use by the application.

The implication is that you wrote this paragraph.  But you didn't: it's copied verbatim from [another Oracle page](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html).  You didn't even link that page at all in your post, let alone **follow the requirements that we have repeatedly explained to you**, that you **must make it clear what is quoted and from where**.

Your claims that you only copied from official documentation or embedded images without licenses are not relevant to whether those sources must be cited.  We are also not confident that this is true; this is not the only case where we've found copied text that did not appear in any source that you linked.  We've found non-official sources that predate your posts, though it's always possible that those sources were also plagiarized.

Given the extensive plagiarism and the difficulty of even finding the original sources at this point, we are disinclined to restore this content to the site, as we cannot be confident that all sources are properly attributed.

Going forward, please carefully read and follow **all** of the guidance we've given you when using material that you did not write yourself.  There's not a lot of guidance to remember: it's just what is in the quote at the top of this answer.  **All** of the rules must be followed for it to be permitted.

Comment: I also note that you need to follow **all of the guidance**, including, but not limited to, "if it's recognizable when you compare the two side-by-side, it needs to give credit."  Your minor wording tweaks [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/34657719/revisions), for instance, still leave _long_ strings of verbatim copied content.  But even if you just changed a couple words to make it not verbatim, while leaving the general structure, it's _still_ copying, and you _still_ need to cite it.  Again, the general rule is whether it's recognizable when comparing side-by-side.

Comment: Also, that post is, like the one discussed in my answer, missing links to the original sources: it only cites one of *at least* three sources (you even removed what links were there in an edit!).  It is unsurprising that it is difficult to remember where content was copied from 7 years ago, but if even you don't know where something came from, it's even more difficult, and sometimes impossible, for a moderator to confirm that all sources have been cited, especially when the sources are no longer online.

Comment: In education, if you were to copy something from a source and change the words, you would still be plagiarising the content. We don't expect a great deal properly quote and cite external sources just like you would do in a professional or educational situation.

Comment: @philipxy Thanks. You're right, that's almost certainly the actual source (though it's _also_ not cited in the post). This shows the difficulty of tracking down sources years later when they aren't properly cited in the first place (we often stop looking once we find a source older than the post). Another possible example of copying from sources other than the product vendor might be "YARN directly handles rack and machine locality in your requests, which is convenient." in [this post](//stackoverflow.com/revisions/34657719/8) from [here](//www.linkedin.com/pulse/comparing-yarn-mesos-mohan-s).

Comment: Version 1 etc of your "YARN" post had (but without saying text was copied) "Have a look at this [article](https://www.quora.com/How-does-YARN-compare-to-Mesos) for comparison between YARN & Mesoslink". But it was removed. And who knows what was copied/rearranged from what. (Googling your quote with 'before:2015' gives https://www.quora.com/How-does-YARN-compare-to-Mesos-What-are-the-key-differences/answer/Jay-Kreps )

Answer (score 11):

You state that

> I have corrected my posts by giving credit where is due.

However you still have answers with significant plagiarism and other problems, perhaps your first step should be to go through your existing visible answers and check they don't have problems because I've only looked at two of your answers.

- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47157838/thread-join-vs-executorservice-awaittermination/47165502#47165502) is simply quotes from the question and links elsewhere. We [don't permit link only answers here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers) which is what this is.
- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20205797/which-part-of-the-cap-theorem-does-cassandra-sacrifice-and-why/68291445#68291445) seems to contain content that is plagiarised from [here](https://www.datastax.com/blog/how-apache-cassandratm-balances-consistency-availability-and-performance). Stating have a look at the linked article is not enough.

Per [how to reference material written by others](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing)

- Provide a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#links) to the original page or answer
     **This you have done.**
- [Quote](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#simple-blockquotes) only the relevant portion
     **this you have not done, the text from the article is not quoted**
- Provide the name of the original author
     **also not done**

Finally let's actually consider [one of the deleted for plagiarism posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22141631/what-is-the-purpose-of-shuffling-and-sorting-phase-in-the-reducer-in-map-reduce/33395854#33395854) you link to in your question...

- yes you link to the source article
- yes you mention who wrote it
- **no**, you don't quote the copied text.

So that post at least is not in a state where a moderator could or should undelete it.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will act on them. Can you please throw  insight into  the posts mentioend in the question?

Comment: @Ravindrababu You don't need any "insight". Go to every one of your posts & properly quote & credit what you didn't write. Your not taking this straightforward obvious action just disingenuously continues unethical behaviour. Also delete posts that are entirely quotes or links.

Comment: @Robert : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47157838/thread-join-vs-executorservice-awaittermination/47165502#47165502 : Here what I highlighted is question asked by Cheg and not the content copied from website. I have corrected it now.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20205797/which-part-of-the-cap-theorem-does-cassandra-sacrifice-and-why/68291445#68291445 : I have deleted it now

Comment: @Ravindrababu At https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47157838/thread-join-vs-executorservice-awaittermination/47165502 (that you mention in your comment) everything other than 'Use `ExecutorService`' is essentially noise.